# How to increment then save an object in mongodb database with node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I'm trying to increment the quantity of an object inside of an array from mongodb database then save it like this :

```
      await user.cart.items.find((each) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(each._id) === JSON.stringify(productId)) {
          if (each.instock > each.quantity) {
            each.quantity += 1;
            console.log("Incremented");
          }
        }
      });
      console.log(user.cart.items);
      await user.save();
```

When I console log `user.cart.items` the field quantity is incremented successfully but when I go to database it is not . Basically the code  `await user.save();` doesn't seem to work .

How can I save the newly updated object in mongodb database with node js ?

Comment: The `find` method returns a _cursor_ and the `forEach` you are iterating over the cursor and accessing one record/document at a time. So, there is a possibility that you can read and update each document within the for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by implementing this piece of code before saving the user model :

```
 user.markModified("cart");
 await user.save();
```